# How to calculate number of each type of atom in a residue in PyMOL?

Tags: software

I have a 3D model of [PDB 4UDC](http://www.rcsb.org/structure/4UDC) (dexamethasone bound to human glucocorticoid receptor), and I'd like to calculate how many atoms of each element are in the dexamethasone molecule (which has the residue name `DEX`) in this model, just to make sure it is correct (as I have added hydrogen atoms with h_add and if I missed a double bond it will be off). So how do I determine how many atoms of each element are present in this residue?

The sort of output I'd be looking for, from whatever answer you provide, would be something like:

C<sub>22</sub>H<sub>29</sub>FO<sub>5</sub>

if I got the bond order and everything else right. Just so you know, as I would dislike it if you thought I meant if we were to count all the atoms up altogether (which would be $22+29+1+5=57$).

Comment: Why not just look at the pdb in an editor and search for DEX. Then cut this out and paste etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not super elegant, but this should work:

```
select resn dex and symbol C
```

Pymol will respond,

```
Selector: selection "sele" defined with 22 atoms.
```

Repeat for H, F, O.

Comment: Well it's a nice and simple method, it's just I'd like to be able to write a program that would represent it C[No]H[No]F[No]O[No] (where No is the number of each and square brackets, [], can be omitted). Is that possible or will have I just have to deal with this output format?

Comment: I'm sure it can be done with a few lines of Python, but not by me.

Answer (score 1):

Download the data and using say, Visual Studio Code (which is free) locate `DEX` in the coordinates by scrolling down. If you open the edit to this post the text is formatted properly)

```
HETATM 2172  C1  DEX A1778       1.049  40.118  -7.466  1.00 33.40           C
HETATM 2173  C2  DEX A1778       0.936  40.967  -6.455  1.00 33.43           C
HETATM 2174  C3  DEX A1778      -0.392  41.247  -5.876  1.00 35.10           C
HETATM 2175  C4  DEX A1778      -1.589  40.609  -6.463  1.00 32.73           C
HETATM 2176  C5  DEX A1778      -1.450  39.719  -7.454  1.00 34.13           C
HETATM 2177  C6  DEX A1778      -2.723  39.089  -8.030  1.00 33.20           C
HETATM 2178  C7  DEX A1778      -2.784  39.329  -9.551  1.00 34.15           C
HETATM 2179  C8  DEX A1778      -1.457  38.973 -10.271  1.00 33.89           C
HETATM 2180  C9  DEX A1778      -0.254  39.730  -9.617  1.00 34.09           C
HETATM 2181  C10 DEX A1778      -0.096  39.369  -8.094  1.00 32.77           C
HETATM 2182  C11 DEX A1778       1.064  39.565 -10.432  1.00 34.52           C
HETATM 2183  C12 DEX A1778       0.895  39.783 -11.960  1.00 33.48           C
HETATM 2184  C13 DEX A1778      -0.244  38.953 -12.593  1.00 34.24           C
HETATM 2185  C14 DEX A1778      -1.548  39.301 -11.772  1.00 33.89           C
HETATM 2186  C15 DEX A1778      -2.675  38.685 -12.622  1.00 35.44           C
HETATM 2187  C16 DEX A1778      -2.182  38.918 -14.084  1.00 35.12           C
HETATM 2188  C17 DEX A1778      -0.695  39.386 -14.019  1.00 35.80           C
HETATM 2189  C18 DEX A1778       0.119  37.433 -12.584  1.00 32.13           C
HETATM 2190  C19 DEX A1778       0.242  37.886  -7.780  1.00 25.76           C
HETATM 2191  C20 DEX A1778       0.187  38.810 -15.131  1.00 35.76           C
HETATM 2192  C21 DEX A1778       1.535  39.421 -15.434  1.00 35.52           C
HETATM 2193  C22 DEX A1778      -3.098  39.926 -14.771  1.00 34.29           C
HETATM 2194  F1  DEX A1778      -0.577  41.091  -9.664  1.00 36.57           F
HETATM 2195  O1  DEX A1778      -0.478  41.974  -4.905  1.00 39.49           O
HETATM 2196  O2  DEX A1778       1.689  38.298 -10.213  1.00 35.91           O
HETATM 2197  O3  DEX A1778      -0.681  40.815 -14.192  1.00 38.27           O
HETATM 2198  O4  DEX A1778      -0.157  37.869 -15.807  1.00 37.29           O
HETATM 2199  O5  DEX A1778       2.356  38.523 -16.169  1.00 35.99           O
```

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Many thanks for edit, I wasn't sure how to format.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have selected the dex residue, and named the selection 'Dex'.
You could've done it using

```
select Dex, resn dex
```

Than you can get the count of each atom using this:

```
from collections import Counter; 
counts = Counter([atom.symbol for atom in cmd.get_model('Dex').atom])
print(counts)
```

This will print

```
Counter({'C': 22, 'H': 29, 'F': 1, 'O': 5})
```

to get the format you asked for:

```
from collections import Counter; 
counts = Counter([atom.symbol for atom in cmd.get_model('Dex').atom])
elements = [atom + str(count) for atom, count in counts.iteritems()]
print(''.join(elements))
```

This will print

```
C22H29F1O5
```

Notice that After the F there is a '1' instead of blank.
I could change that if you'd like with a bit more code.